# mysql commands are not working properly from terminal

Tags: mysql, sql

I used to access mysql through command from terminal using

```
mysql -u root -p
```

And after that I also put the password of mysql.
Now I want to show my databases using the command given below.

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES
    ->
```

But it shows nothing.
So please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing wrong - everything works as supposed to do.

You typed an incomplete command and because this you see

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES
    ->
```

The mysql CLI waits for the completion of the command `SHOW DATABASES`. type `;` followed by a <kbd>Return</kbd>

The correct syntax is

```
show databases;
```

The commands are not case sensitive.